# Is the order of operations in a constructor guaranteed?

Tags: java

This is a question about the behaviour of Java's default constructors. In the following code snipped

```
public class LocalIDSupplier implements IDSupplier {
private BiMap<BMTPropertyContainer, String> localid = HashBiMap.create();
private BiMap<String, BMTPropertyContainer> inverse = localid.inverse();

    //Some methods
}
```

two instance variables are initialised, yet one depends on the other, so is it guaranteed for all JVM's that the default constructor will initialise these two variables in the order in which they are declared? Obviously one could insure it by creating an explicit constructor, but the compiler does not have a problem with this. Is there any problem with this type of dependency in initialisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) states

> Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers
>   for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers
>   to the corresponding instance variables, **in the left-to-right order in
>   which they appear textually in the source code for the class.** If
>   execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then
>   no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes
>   abruptly with that same exception. [...]

Comment: Or in short: Yes, the order in which they are declared is preserved for the order of initialization, and no, there is no problem with this type of dependency in initialisation :) Beware of 'static' tho.